# Invalid property exception in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring in my application , When i am loading the springApplicationContext to get the beans i am getting the errors

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException:
>   Invalid property "abc"

Even though there is a property `abc` and the setter for that property in the bean.

This is a weird error i know , but i can't figure out where is the problem.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks!
Pratik

Comment: Are you sure the exception is for the bean with `abc` setter? Can you post a full stack trace as well as appropriate fragments of bean class and spring context?

Comment: Is your setter `public`?

Comment: Post the class and the Spring config XML so we can see both.

Comment: Sorry guys , that was my problem . The build was picking up old jar from the maven repository.  :( :(

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that the property has both a public setter and getter. In case of an `AnyObject` property it should look like:

```
private AnyObject abc;
public AnyObject getAbc() { return abc; }
public void setAbc(AnyObject abc) { this.abc = abc; }
```

There is however one special case: in case of a `boolean` property it should look like:

```
private boolean abc;
public boolean isAbc() { return abc; }
public void setAbc(boolean abc) { this.abc = abc; }
```

Note the `is` prefix instead of `get`.

Comment: Getter is **not** necessary. If it **is** declared, then it indeed needs to conform to javabean spec (btw, `isXXX` is also optional for booleans; `getXXX` works just as well).

Answer (score -1):

I remeber the similar question at Spring forums. It was found out that there was a setter signature like

```
public class MyClass {

    private Aggregated field;

    public MyClass setField(Aggregated field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

I.e. the setter's return type was not *void*.

Anyway, Spring uses standard [Instrospector](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) for processing class properties. Try it with your class and check if target property is found.